# Time complexity of BFS and DFS on a BinaryTree: Why O(n)?

Tags: binary-tree, depth-first-search, traversal, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

The time complexity of BFS, or DFS, on a graph is O(V+E) because we traverse all the nodes and edges of the graph. (I get that) But for a binary tree, the time complexity of BFS and DFS is O(V)... Why is that?

I am assuming is because of the following: O(V+E) = O(V + V-1) = O(2V) = O(V). Is this the correct reasoning? If not, an intuitive explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All trees have `n - 1` edges, `n` being the number of nodes. The time complexity is still technically O(V + E), but that equates to O(n + (n-1)) = O(n).

Answer (score 1):

you can actually see it in a different way, without the use of graphs.

n is the number of nodes.
And denote the steps required for traversing through the whole tree f(n) (note, the time complexity will then be O(f(n))).

Consider that for each node we need to:
either visit that, or traverse it through on the left, and traverse it through on the right, and eventually return on it at most one time.

All these 4 operations can happen at most Once for each node. Agree?
From this we deduce that f(n) <= 4n.

Agree? Because for each node we can have at most those 4 operations. Remind we have n nodes.

Obviously, at the same time, n <= f(n)
because we need to visit each node at least once.

Therefore,

n <= f(n) <= 4n

Applying the O notation, we get

O(n) <= O(f(n)) <= O(4n)

Reminding that O(4n) = O(n) by properties of O (invariance due to multiplicative constants different from 0), we get that

O(n) <= O(f(n)) <= O(4n) = O(n),

or

O(n) <= O(f(n)) <= O(n)

Notice the left side of this chain of inequality is equal to the right side of the chain, meaning that it is not only a chain of inequality, but a chain of equalities, or

O(n) = O(f(n)) = O(n)

meaning that the complexity is O(n)